# Map/Reduce differences between Couchbase & CloudAnt

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce, cloudant, couchbase

I've been playing around with Couchbase Server and now just tried replicating my local db to Cloudant, but am getting conflicting results for my map/reduce function pair to build a set of unique tags with their associated projects...

```
// map.js
function(doc) {
  if (doc.tags) {
    for(var t in doc.tags) {
      emit(doc.tags[t], doc._id);
    }
  }
}

// reduce.js
function(key,values,rereduce) {
  if (!rereduce) {
    var res=[];
    for(var v in values) {
      res.push(values[v]);
    }
    return res;
  } else {
    return values.length;
  }
}
```

In Cloudbase server this returns JSON like:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"3d","value":["project1","project3","project8","project10"]},
{"key":"agents","value":["project2"]},
{"key":"fabrication","value":["project3","project5"]}
]}
```

That's exactly what I wanted & expected. However, the same query on the Cloudant replica, returns this:

```
{"rows":[
{"key":"3d","value":4},
{"key":"agents","value":1},
{"key":"fabrication","value":2}
]}
```

So it somehow only returns the length of the value array... Highly confusing & am grateful for any insights by some M&R ninjas... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to reduce/re-reduce implicitly rather than depending on the `rereduce` parameter.

```
function(doc) { // map
  if (doc.tags) {
    for(var t in doc.tags) {
      emit(doc.tags[t], {id:doc._id, tag:doc.tags[t]});
    }
  }
}
```

Then reduce checks whether it is accumulating document ids from the **identical** tag, or whether it is just counting different tags.

```
function(keys, vals, rereduce) {
  var initial_tag = vals[0].tag;

  return vals.reduce(function(state, val) {
    if(initial_tag && val.tag === initial_tag) {
      // Accumulate ids which produced this tag.
      var ids = state.ids;
      if(!ids)
        ids = [ state.id ]; // Build initial list from the state's id.
      return { tag: val.tag, 
             , ids: ids.concat([val.id])
             };
    } else {
      var state_count = state.ids ? state.ids.length : state;
      var val_count   = val.ids   ? val.ids.length   : val;
      return state_count + val_count;
    } 
  })
}
```

(I didn't test this code, but you get the idea. As long as the `tag` value is the same, it *doesn't matter* whether it's a reduce or rereduce. Once different tags start reducing together, it detects that because the `tag` value will change. So at that point just start accumulating.

I have used this trick before, although IMO it's rarely worth it.

Also in **your specific case**, this is a dangerous reduce function. You are building a wide list to see all the docs that have a tag. CouchDB likes tall lists, not fat lists. If you want to see all the docs that have a tag, you could map them.

```
for(var a = 0; a < doc.tags.length; a++) {
  emit(doc.tags[a], doc._id);
}
```

Now you can query `/db/_design/app/_view/docs_by_tag?key="3d"` and you should get

```
{"total_rows":287,"offset":30,"rows":[
{"id":"project1","key":"3d","value":"project1"}
{"id":"project3","key":"3d","value":"project3"}
{"id":"project8","key":"3d","value":"project8"}
{"id":"project10","key":"3d","value":"project10"}
]}
```

Comment: Thank you, people for all your insights! (and sorry it's taken me so long to reply, got pulled away) I've managed to work my way around, but still find it sometimes hard to fully grok the reduce part without any debugging feature in couchdb. Being able to see the intermediate results would do wonders to better understand what's happening...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is exactly the behavior you would expect given your reduce function.  The key part is this:

```
else {
return values.length;
}
```

In Cloudant, rereduce is always called (since the reduce needs to span over multiple shards.)  In this case, rereduce calls values.length, which will only return the length of the array.

Comment: I see, but how can I write this query so it produces the same result (#1) on both platforms? I don't care right now (well I do :) that my reduce function isn't perfect, but I would have assumed a consistent behavior...

Comment: +1, Alan. Toxi, I suggest you rewrite so that you can "smell" a re-reduce vs. an initial reduce, without checking the parameter passed from couch. I've done that before, so I'll make a try as an actual answer, for better formatting.

Comment: You just need to remember that Cloudant _always_ calls rereduce so if you want the two to be consistent you need your rereduce clause to match your reduce clause.  As a side note: any nontrivial reduce function in CouchDB will make use of rereduce so it's a good idea to understand the mechanics under the hood.  See e.g. http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Reduce_vs_rereduce

Comment: I ignore rereduce in production all the time. I'll show you in my answer.